# Как замедлить часть кода,но не замедлять весь код?

Tags: python, pygame

Делаю небольшую игру на Pygame.

В моем коде есть функция, в которой `while True` запускает меню. В этом меню есть блок, который постоянно перемещает спрайт на рандомное кол-во пикселей.

Нужно сделать так, чтоб замедлился не весь код, а только этот блок (чтоб спрайт перемещался не моментально, а с задержкой в 3 секунды).

Использовал `pygame.time.delay()` и `time.sleep()`, но они замедляют весь код. 
Подскажите, что можно сделать. Если нужно, то скину код.

Comment: а можно код перемещения? самый очевидный способ завести переменную, которая будет влиять на скорость и изменять ее в нужную сторону

Comment: Добавьте вместо `sleep` условие, которое будет срабатывать раз в 3 секунды, сверяясь с системным таймером

Answer (score 3):

Задержек быть не должно. Чтобы выполнять некоторый код с какой-то периодичностью, надо [генерировать события](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.set_timer) с этой периодичностью и обрабатывать их:

```
import pygame

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 200))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
pygame.display.set_caption('Timer demo')

MOVE_DOWN_DELAY = 500
MOVE_DOWN_EVENT = pygame.USEREVENT + 1

pygame.time.set_timer(MOVE_DOWN_EVENT, MOVE_DOWN_DELAY)

dot = pygame.Rect(150, 10, 10, 10)

while True:
    clock.tick(50)

    if pygame.event.get(pygame.QUIT): break

    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == MOVE_DOWN_EVENT:
            dot.move_ip(0, 10)

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (150, 150, 150), dot)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: еще бы пару комментариев о том, что тут происходит и как оно работает

Comment: @Viktorov думаете надо? Код элементарный, в тексте описано, что он делает, и ссылка на документацию тоже дана.

Comment: Я так увлекся кодом, что не заметил ссылку на доку. Съедаю свою шляпу =)